# Akka actors output not as expected

Tags: akka

Following [akka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/guide/tutorial_1.html), for example in section 'The actor lifecycle', for me output is not as documented. What I get is:

> first started
>
> second started
>
> second stopped

Code is:

```
object StartStopActorMain extends App {
  val first = ActorSystem(StartStopActor1(), "firstActor")
  first ! "stop"
}

object StartStopActor1 {
  def apply() =
      Behaviors.setup(context => new StartStopActor1(context))
}

class StartStopActor1(context: ActorContext[String]) extends 
      AbstractBehavior[String](context) {
    println("first started")
    context.spawn(StartStopActor2(), "second")

    override def onMessage(msg: String): Behavior[String] =
        msg match {
          case "stop" => Behaviors.stopped
    }

    override def onSignal: PartialFunction[Signal, Behavior[String]] = {
        case PostStop =>
         println("first stopped")
         this
    }
}

object StartStopActor2 {

  def apply() =
      Behaviors.setup(context => new StartStopActor2(context))

 }

class StartStopActor2(context: ActorContext[String]) extends 
        AbstractBehavior[String](context) {
     println("second started")

    override def onMessage(msg: String): Behavior[String] = Behaviors.unhandled

   override def onSignal: PartialFunction[Signal, Behavior[String]] = {
         case PostStop =>
           println("second stopped")
           this
    }
}
```

Anything I am missing here? I copied code from there itself.

Answer (score 1):

With the amount of information you provide it is impossible to answer your question. But my best guess is that your JVM exits before the first actor has a change to print its stop message.

**Edit**

It may also be that the Akka documentation is wrong: the first actor replaces its behavior with `Behaviors.stopped`, thus the PostStop signal is not delivered to the StartStopActor1 behavior but to the stopped behavior. I remember implementing it this way a few years back, with the rationale that the PostStop hook is not necessary when the actor voluntarily terminates: any code that you would want to run for PostStop can also be run before returning `Behaviors.stopped`.

Comment: I have added my code. class StartStopActor1 spawns actor StartStopActor2. And when it receives message 'stop' it returns Behaviors.stopped.

Comment: Thanks, your comment reminded me of another plausible explanation for the behavior you observe.